# Asterisk hangs up calls after 10 seconds

Tags: asterisk

I am having some trouble with my asterisk install hanging up calls.

Initially I was having no audio on my calls so I opened up the ports to my gsu gateway which is on a different network then my asterisk box. I opened up the port on the gsm gateway side with is behind not and that resolved the audio issues

Now the issue is that asterisk drops the calls. I have checked and the rtp packets stream is only sending packets and doesn't seem to be getting anything back.

The asterisk box is hosted on vultr with Ubuntu server.

Any idea on whats going on?

Comment: Please provide logs so I can investigate

Comment: alright which logs would you like? i have the message log, for rtp should i just copy the debug output?

Comment: I need logs from Asterisk CLI

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Bwyu0bmV This is my entire log with sip and rtp debug on. I have blocked out the ips address with XXX maintaining the original format. I have also xxx the phone number maintaining the same format. thanks

Comment: This is not what I need. I need output from Asterisk CLI. Run in shell `asterisk -vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvdr` and make a call and paste all logs here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/k3N3r9Yr here the log. I did exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Hangup in 10-12 seconds after call started usually issued by incorrect nat settings. Asterisk can't send back response to softphone/hardphone and hangup line(it think no internet connection to device).

See http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SIP+NAT+solutions

In your case it also can be firewall or bad virtualization setup.

Comment: well i had nat issues at first when i had no audio traffic. I made the nat changes and now i have the audio but i have the hangup issue. Ive checked all settings

Comment: Now you have rdp issue solved, but not SIP control protocol messages. see "sip set debug on" for more info.

Comment: well i posted a two different log on top, if you wouldnt mind taking a look id appreciate it

Comment: In log you can see retransmit. That mean client not reply on packet. So it is nat or firewall, as i say you before without any log(hangup time is very specific).

Comment: the problem is knowing where this nat/firewall is. Is it on the atahualpa side or the softswitch side or the softphone side

Comment: i have tried to open all the ports i need but it seems my softphone only works if my computer is dmz'd. The sip port is also a random high number even though i have supposedly opened the sip ports in my network. What am i doing wrong